# Multipart entity not executing correctly using AsyncTask

Tags: java, android

I am sending the xml to php using MultipartEntity in android.

But I am having issue in this.

```
try {
    MultipartEntity mp = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    HttpPost method = new HttpPost(connUrl);
    method.setEntity(mp);
    mp.addPart("xml", new StringBody(xml));
} catch(Exception e) {
    .....
} finally {
     .............
}
```

When control reach at one line of try block. Its enter in finally block without executing other line of this try block and catch block. Can anyone suggest me what could be problem in this.

Comment: Doesn't it enter the catch block?

Comment: @Pescis Not its not enter in catch block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem lastly.

Using this code.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(connUrl);
try {
    List<BasicNameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("xml", xml));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    ........
} catch(Exception e) {
    .....
} finally {
      .............
}
```